# Checking attribute value from a web page

Tags: javascript, html

I got attribute (capacity_gold) in a table of a web page. It is a marketplace so the values are constantly changing and I want to create a simple script which will alert me when the value of an attribute is greater than 100.

I found current value of an attribute in html table with id = "capacity_gold".

```
<td id="capacity_gold" class="center"></td>
```

Comment: how often your data will updated?

Comment: Please provide a full code example (preferably on JSBin or some such service) so people who see the question can reproduce the problem/context and give you a helpful answer. The code sample you have provided assumes the presence of `PremiumExchange` which is not (at least in my limited knowledge) available as a part of jQuery/javascript and seems to be specific to your application


Some tips on asking good questions on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try setinterval..

Comment: I would first see if they have an API. You cannot get jQuery to periodically load a site not from the same origin as the script unless they implement and support CORS

Comment: Chirag, I tried to provide the shortest possible code. I can provide you a PremiumExchange.js, but it is too long and messy.
https://gist.github.com/r8w9a5k/7f7b647422dad022ab3842e8daf6b56c#file-premiumexchange-js

Comment: mplungajn, I will find it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am implementing `setInterval` for 2 seconds;

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>set Interval</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="target">102</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 setInterval((checkTargetValue),2000);

 function checkTargetValue() {
  let targetValue = document.getElementById('target').innerHTML;
  if (targetValue > 100) {console.log("crossed 100..")}
     else { console.log("havent crossed yet"); }
 }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Rajkumar Somasundaram, thank you for your help. Your code works perfectly ! I added this code to the browser's console and now I am alerted! :)

Comment: May I ask you why you didn't use var instead of let? :)

Comment: I am trying to move towards es6; you should read about let vs var ; Very soon you will no longer find js developers using var;

Comment: Ok, thank you.
I wanted to mark your answer +1, but i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Its ok.. let that be your next target (gaining enough reputation to upvote).. All the best